# Android:Google map current location and other marker points

Tags: android, google-maps, balloon, currentlocation

I'm developing an android Google map app. How to create a current location ,balloon overlay and other marker location points.

I am creating Other marker location points in (CustomMap.java)

Here I want to current location also.Please help me

**CustomMap.java**

```
 public class CustomMap extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {

MapView mapView;
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
Drawable drawable;
Drawable drawable2;
CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> itemizedOverlay;
CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> itemizedOverlay2;
double longitude;
double latitude;

long start;
long stop;
int x, y;
int lati = 0; 
int longit = 0;
GeoPoint touchedPoint;
public boolean overlay_status=false;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // making it full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_map);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    // first overlay
    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
    itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem>(drawable, mapView);

    //first overlay in first pinpoint
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(13.0094444*1E6),(int)(77.5508333*1E6));
    CustomOverlayItem overlayItem = new CustomOverlayItem(point, "ISKCON Temple Bangalore(1997)", 
            "(ISKCON Temple, Chord Rd, Mahalakshmipuram Layout, Nagapura, Bangalore, Karnataka, India)", 
            "http://www.iskcon-bda.org/data/HKH.jpg");
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);

    //first overlay in second pinpoint
    GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint((int)(12.8008*1E6),(int)(77.5756*1E6));
    CustomOverlayItem overlayItem2 = new CustomOverlayItem(point2, "Bannerghatta National Park", 
            "(Bannerghatta Biological Park is carved out of the Bannerghatta National Park in the year 2002)", 
            "http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://travel.sulekha.com/" +
            "india/karnataka/bangalore/photos/bannerghatta-national-park-25.jpg&imgrefurl=http://travel.sulekha.com/" +
            "a-visit-to-bannerghatta-national-park_bangalore-travelogue-3541.htm&h=194&w=259&sz=1&tbnid=K5TNPwXHgihgRM:&tbnh=" +
            "119&tbnw=160&zoom=1&usg=__MFNGL1C2InXP7jw7XmEi4ym45NY=&docid=d78iF3T5ditWeM&itg=1&hl=en&sa=X&ei=" +
            "CpwQUdOmHIPUrQe0m4H4Bg&sqi=2&ved=0CHwQ_B0wCw");        
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem2);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    // second overlay
    drawable2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker2);
    itemizedOverlay2 = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem>(drawable2, mapView);

    //second overlay in third pinpoint
    GeoPoint point3 = new GeoPoint((int)(12.8339956*1E6),(int)(77.4009816*1E6));
    CustomOverlayItem overlayItem3 = new CustomOverlayItem(point3, "Wonderla Bangalore(2005)", 
            "(Wonderla is an amusement park located near Bidadi, 28 kilometres Bangalore, spanning 82 acres of land)",
            "http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://www.yohyoh.com/places-tourism/pictures/wb3.jpg&imgrefurl=http://" +
            "www.yohyoh.com/places-tourism/view.php/popular-tours/Karnataka/Bangalore/wonderla-bangalore/561/8192987807&h=" +
            "194&w=259&sz=1&tbnid=RoLC5gzRHP6VSM:&tbnh=160&tbnw=213&zoom=1&usg=__ShDQAmQ0zjQaKbsy0A63BokHAmk=" +
            "&docid=J1aN09WXjvHw4M&itg=1&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Sp0QUbvIEMHjrAfTy4GgBA&ved=0CNMBEPwdMAo");
    itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(overlayItem3);

    //second overlay in third pinpoint
    GeoPoint point4 = new GeoPoint((int)(12.8385923*1E6),(int)(77.661710599*1E6));
    CustomOverlayItem overlayItem4 = new CustomOverlayItem(point4, "Wipro Technologies,Bangalore", 
            "(Wipro Technologies, Electronics City Phase 1, Electronics City, Bangalore, Karnataka 560100, India)", 
            "http://www.electronic-city.in/companies/profile/wipro/wipro-electronic-city.jpg");     
    itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(overlayItem4);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay2);



    // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

    // Getting the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Getting Current Location
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if(location!=null){
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

    String address = "";
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
            getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());

   latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating an instance of GeoPoint corresponding to latitude and longitude
    GeoPoint point5 = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude * 1E6), (int)(longitude*1E6));

    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
            point.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
            point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                for (int index = 0; index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                    address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
            }
            tvLocation.setText("Address :" +  address  );
    }
    catch (IOException e) {                
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.url);
    itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem>(drawable, mapView);

    mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
    itemizedOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
     @Override
    public void run() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
     }
     });
    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

    // Locating the Geographical point in the Map
    mapController.animateTo(point5);
    itemizedOverlay.enableMyLocation();
     mapView.postInvalidate();
    // Getting list of overlays available in the map
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    CustomOverlayItem currentLocation = new CustomOverlayItem(point, "Current Location", "Latitude : " + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude, null);

    // Adding the mark to the overlay
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(currentLocation);

    // Clear Existing overlays in the map
    mapOverlays.clear();
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);



    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

    //Contains Displaying the pinpoint
    final MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.animateTo(point);
    mc.setZoom(16);
    }else {

        // example restoring focused state of overlays
        int focused;
        focused = savedInstanceState.getInt("focused_1", -1);
        if (focused >= 0) {
            itemizedOverlay.setFocus(itemizedOverlay.getItem(focused));
        }
        focused = savedInstanceState.getInt("focused_2", -1);
        if (focused >= 0) {
            itemizedOverlay2.setFocus(itemizedOverlay2.getItem(focused));
        }

    }




    Touchy t = new Touchy();
    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    mapOverlays.add(t);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    // example saving focused state of overlays
    if (itemizedOverlay.getFocus() != null) outState.putInt("focused_1", itemizedOverlay.getLastFocusedIndex());
    if (itemizedOverlay2.getFocus() != null) outState.putInt("focused_2", itemizedOverlay2.getLastFocusedIndex());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}

//Contains creating the option menu items 
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, 0, 1, "Remove Overlay");
    menu.add(0, 1, 1, "set Overlay");
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.drawable.home_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(overlay_status==false)
    {
     menu.findItem(1).setVisible(false);
     menu.findItem(0).setVisible(true);

    //overlay_status=true;
    }
    else
    {
         menu.findItem(0).setVisible(false);
         menu.findItem(1).setVisible(true);

        // overlay_status=false;
    }
 return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.home1:
         finish();
        return true;
    case 0:

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "remove overlay ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // example hiding balloon before removing overlay
                    if (itemizedOverlay.getFocus() != null) {
                        itemizedOverlay.hideBalloon();
                    }
                    mapOverlays.remove(itemizedOverlay);
                    mapView.invalidate();
                    overlay_status=true;
                return true;    
    case 1:


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "set overlay ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (itemizedOverlay.getFocus() != null) {
            itemizedOverlay.getBalloonBottomOffset();
        }
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
             mapView.bringToFront();

             overlay_status=false;
             return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}

class Touchy extends Overlay{
    List<Address> address;
    String display = "";
    String display1;
    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e,MapView m){
        if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            start = e.getEventTime();
            x = (int)e.getX();
            y = (int)e.getY();
            touchedPoint = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(x, y);
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());    
            try{
                address = geocoder.getFromLocation(touchedPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6, touchedPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);
                if(address.size() > 0){

                    for(int i = 0; i<address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                        display +=address.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), display, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }catch(IOException e1){

            }
            finally
            {
                display1=display;
                display=" ";
            }

            }
        if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            stop = e.getEventTime();
        }

    /**contains the creating a Alert Dialog Box (place apinpoint, get address, Toggle View)
     * In Dialog Box Maximum three buttens
     */
    if(stop - start > 1000){
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(CustomMap.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("pick an Option");
        alert.setMessage("I told to pick an option");

        alert.setButton("place a pinpoint", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                CustomOverlayItem overlayItem = new CustomOverlayItem(touchedPoint,"Address:",display1, display1);
 //                 SimpleItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new SimpleItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);
                CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> itemOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem>(drawable, mapView);
 //                 CustomPinpoint custom = new CustomPinpoint(drawable, CustomMap.this);
 //                 custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
                itemOverlay.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
                itemOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
                mapOverlays.add(itemOverlay);
            }
        });

        alert.setButton2("get address", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());    
                try{
                    List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(touchedPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6, touchedPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);
                    if(address.size() > 0){
                        String display = "";
                        for(int i = 0; i<address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                            display +=address.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), display, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                }catch(IOException e){

                }
            }
        });

        alert.setButton3("Toggle View", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                if(mapView.isSatellite()){
                    mapView.setSatellite(false);
                    mapView.setStreetView(true);
                }else{ 
                    mapView.setStreetView(false);
                    mapView.setSatellite(true);
                }

            }
        });


        alert.show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

 }
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    lati = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
    longit = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
    GeoPoint ourLocation = new GeoPoint(lati, longit);
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(ourLocation, "What's up?", "2nd String");
    CustomPinpoint custom = new CustomPinpoint(drawable, CustomMap.this);
    custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
    mapOverlays.add(custom);

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

 }
```

Comment: android map api v1 is deprecated using android map api v2, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Answer (score 3):

Try this AndroidHive Google code

Google Map Link    [Android Working with Google Places and Maps Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/)

```
public class SinglePlaceActivity extends Activity {
// flag for Internet connection status
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

// Connection detector class
ConnectionDetector cd;

// Alert Dialog Manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

// Google Places
GooglePlaces googlePlaces;

// Place Details
PlaceDetails placeDetails;

// Progress dialog
ProgressDialog pDialog;

// KEY Strings
public static String KEY_REFERENCE = "reference"; // id of the place

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_place);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Place referece id
    String reference = i.getStringExtra(KEY_REFERENCE);

    // Calling a Async Background thread
    new LoadSinglePlaceDetails().execute(reference);
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load Google places
 * */
class LoadSinglePlaceDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SinglePlaceActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading profile ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Profile JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String reference = args[0];

        // creating Places class object
        googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();

        // Check if used is connected to Internet
        try {
            placeDetails = googlePlaces.getPlaceDetails(reference);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed Places into LISTVIEW
                 * */
                if(placeDetails != null){
                    String status = placeDetails.status;

                    // check place deatils status
                    // Check for all possible status
                    if(status.equals("OK")){
                        if (placeDetails.result != null) {
                            String name = placeDetails.result.name;
                            String address = placeDetails.result.formatted_address;
                            String phone = placeDetails.result.formatted_phone_number;
                            String latitude = Double.toString(placeDetails.result.geometry.location.lat);
                            String longitude = Double.toString(placeDetails.result.geometry.location.lng);

                            Log.d("Place ", name + address + phone + latitude + longitude);

                            // Displaying all the details in the view
                            // single_place.xml
                            TextView lbl_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
                            TextView lbl_address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
                            TextView lbl_phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone);
                            TextView lbl_location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);

                            // Check for null data from google
                            // Sometimes place details might missing
                            name = name == null ? "Not present" : name; // if name is null display as "Not present"
                            address = address == null ? "Not present" : address;
                            phone = phone == null ? "Not present" : phone;
                            latitude = latitude == null ? "Not present" : latitude;
                            longitude = longitude == null ? "Not present" : longitude;

                            lbl_name.setText(name);
                            lbl_address.setText(address);
                            lbl_phone.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Phone:</b> " + phone));
                            lbl_location.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Latitude:</b> " + latitude + ", <b>Longitude:</b> " + longitude));
                        }
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")){
                        alert.showAlertDialog(SinglePlaceActivity.this, "Near Places",
                                "Sorry no place found.",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("UNKNOWN_ERROR"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(SinglePlaceActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry unknown error occured.",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(SinglePlaceActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry query limit to google places is reached",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("REQUEST_DENIED"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(SinglePlaceActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry error occured. Request is denied",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("INVALID_REQUEST"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(SinglePlaceActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry error occured. Invalid Request",
                                false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(SinglePlaceActivity.this, "Places Error",
                                "Sorry error occured.",
                                false);
                    }
                }else{
                    alert.showAlertDialog(SinglePlaceActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry error occured.",
                            false);
                }

            }
        });

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 mapView.getOverlays().add(locationoverlay);
locationoverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
 @Override
public void run() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 mapView.getOverlays().add(locationoverlay);
 }
 });
 locationoverlay.enableMyLocation();
 mapView.postInvalidate();
```

Above code will provide the current location in android default marker overlay

Comment: When I touch map NullPointerException error came 02-05 07:04:06.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2572): java.lang.NullPointerException